# HTML css jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
<div class="carousel-inner product-slider-inner">
<?php while($featurepro = mysqli_fetch_assoc($featurequery)): ?>
<div class="item">
<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 text-center">
<a href="#"><img src="<?=$featurepro['image'];?>" class="img-responsive"></a>
<h5 class="text-center"><?=$featurepro['title'];?></h5>
<h6 class="text-center"><?=money($featurepro['price']);?></h6>
<div class="btn btn--border btn--primary btn--animated"><a href="" class="anchor"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

i want to add a active class in first item using jquery but i dont how i select particular item it has more item in slider but only first item has a class active

Comment: Add your jQuery code

Comment: and i use 2 or more slider so it also has item class, so i want to add by particular class, like... in css we can declare class by particular element without giving him class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to target `.item` for example using [:first-of-type](https://api.jquery.com/first-of-type-selector/)

if this doesn't work or it selects more than desired then you need to add more code.

```js
$(".product-slider-inner>.item:first-of-type").addClass("active");
```

```css
.item.active {
  color: red;
  font-size: 120%;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>


<div class="carousel-inner product-slider-inner">
  <?php while($featurepro = mysqli_fetch_assoc($featurequery)): ?>
  <div class="item">Something
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 text-center">
      <a href="#"><img src="<?=$featurepro['image'];?>" class="img-responsive"></a>
      <h5 class="text-center">
        <?=$featurepro['title'];?>
      </h5>
      <h6 class="text-center">
        <?=money($featurepro['price']);?>
      </h6>
      <div class="btn btn--border btn--primary btn--animated"><a href="" class="anchor"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></span></a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: hey hi can you tell me 302 redirect problem, i have a product page which send product info into database but i am using same page for validating. but sometime it give me 201ok but sometimes it give me 302 redirect me somewhere else but i need to use header() for same page

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use the `.first()` method

```
$('.item').first().addClass('active')
```

Comment: This will select the first element with the class `item`, if it is not working then there is another problem with your code. If you could post more of it we might be able to help you

Comment: i have many other item class in my page so tell me by targeting particular item class using their parent classes or other method

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use jquery, you can use `first`
https://api.jquery.com/first/

If you want to access the first div with class='item'

`$( ".item" ).first().addClass( "active" );`